# Round only the decimal points to the nearest tens in Java like 1.17 to 1.20

Tags: java, math

How can I round a given number, for example 1.17 to 1.20 not 1.0 or 2.0. I was trying to print a list of centimeters, feet and inches from 4 ft to 7 ft. I've got the centimeters, and feet part working but the inches part is not as intended.

Here is the function I use to generate the list and log the results

```
private void print() {
        final float oneInch = 2.54f;
        final float oneFt = 30.48f;
        final float end = oneInch * 12 * 7;
        float start = oneInch * 12 * 4;
        int cm;
        int ft;
        float in;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        decimalFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        while (start <= end) {
            if (sb.length() > 0) {
                sb.replace(0, sb.length(), "");
            }

            cm = (int) start;
            sb.append(cm);
            sb.append(" cm, ");

            ft = (int) (start / oneFt);
            in = Float.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(start / oneFt - ft));
            if (in >= 1.0f) {
                ++ft;
                in = 0f;
            }
            sb.append(ft);
            sb.append(" ft ");
            if (in > 0) {
                sb.append(String.valueOf(in).replace("0.", ""));
            }
            start += oneInch;
            Log.i("measure", sb.toString());
        }
    }
```

Here  is the logged values

```
121 cm, 4 ft
124 cm, 4 ft 08
127 cm, 4 ft 17
129 cm, 4 ft 25
```

it is printing as 4 ft 08, how can I print the inches part as whole numbers, like this?

```
121 cm, 4 ft
124 cm, 4 ft 1
127 cm, 4 ft 2
129 cm, 4 ft 3
```

Comment: It looks like you've already found how to round 1.17 to 1.2?  You may need to use `"#.#"` instead of `"#.##"`

Comment: As for the second part of your question, it looks like your inches are off by a factor of 10?  You should be able to divide by 10.0 and round

Comment: To round the first decimal of a number you can simply go and use: `Math.round(num % 1 * 10)`. For example for `4.18` this will result in `2`. You can use `Math.round(num % 1 * 10) / 10.d` if you want this to be `0.2` instead and `(int) num + (Math.round(num % 1 * 10) / 10.d)` for `4.2`.

Comment: @phflack I've already tried that , but it is repeating some values, for example 4 ft 3 twice for 129 and 132

Comment: @Ben It's easier to use `Math.round(num * 10.0) / 10.0` for 4.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use Strings for numeric operations.  When doing math, use math operators and math functions:

```
in = (start / oneFt - ft) * 12;
```

You don’t need to round your numbers at all.  Let the DecimalFormat do the rounding:

```
if (in > 0) {
    sb.append(decimalFormat.format(in));
}
```

Comment: That string function is used to remove the leading `0.` from the `in` variable

Comment: Your `in` variable contained a fractional number of feet.  0.5 feet is 0.5×12=6 inches.